# How to flag only one instance of an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

In my android application, I have a button that, when clicked opens another activity. The problem is that the user could keep tapping on that button many times quickly and it would open a lot of those new activities. How can I force it so that only one of those activities can be open at a time?

I want to avoid doing big things like disabling buttons or putting loading screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scenario is as simple as you describe, you can launch the Activity with [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP). That will prevent new instances from being created if one has already been shown. A crude example:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalledActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Rapid-pressing on the button will create many instances of `CalledActivity` without the Intent flag.

Comment: Why does it need to be run 1 second later. Is that required become of some timing issue?

Comment: @omega No, not at all! That was just an example to easily reproduce the "press the button multiple times" issue you describe. :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. This ensures only one instance of the Activity will be created:

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP