# How to flag only 1 instance of dialog in android?

Tags: android, dialog

In my android app, I have a button that when clicked opens a dialog. The problem is that the user could keep tapping on that button for many times quickly and it would open a lot of those new dialogs. How can I force it so that only one of those dialogs can be open at a time?

I want to avoid doing big things like disabling buttons, global variables, or putting loading screens etc...

Thanks.

The solution for activities would be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalledActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

But how can I do this for dialogs?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flag only 1 instance of activity in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613026/how-to-flag-only-1-instance-of-activity-in-android)

Comment: Kepp track of your dialogs. Don't open it if you opened it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) to host your dialog. You can use [isAdded](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) function to see if the dialog was already added and only show it if it wasn't.